# Save result of operator in Apache Airflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow

Several operators allow to pull data but I never managed to use the results.

For example:
https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_get_data.py

This operator can be called as follow:

```
get_data = BigQueryGetDataOperator(
      task_id='get_data_from_bq',
      dataset_id='test_dataset',
      table_id='Transaction_partitions',
      max_results='100',
      selected_fields='DATE',
      bigquery_conn_id='airflow-service-account'
      )
```

Yet, get_data is of type DAG but line 116 says "return table_data".
To be clear, the operator works and retrieve the data, I just don't understand how to use the data retrieve/where it is located.

How do I get the data using "get_data" above?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The way you would use `get_data` is in the next task can be a `PythonOperator` which you can then use to process the data.

```
get_data = BigQueryGetDataOperator(
      task_id='get_data_from_bq',
      dataset_id='test_dataset',
      table_id='Transaction_partitions',
      max_results='100',
      selected_fields='DATE',
      bigquery_conn_id='airflow-service-account'
      )

def process_data_from_bq(**kwargs):
      ti = kwargs['ti']
      bq_data = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='get_data_from_bq')
      # Now bq_data here would have your data in Python list
      print(bq_data)

process_data = PythonOperator(
      task_id='process_data_from_bq',
      python_callable=process_bq_data,
      provide_context=True
      )

get_data >> process_data
```

PS: I am the author of `BigQueryGetDataOperator` and Airflow committer / PMC

Comment: Nitpicking here: your print statement will fail because `data` is undeclared.

Comment: @dboshardy Updated

Comment: "An XCom is identified by a key (essentially its name), as well as the task_id and dag_id it came from. They can have any (serializable) value, but they are only designed for **small amounts of data; do not use them to pass around large values**, like dataframes." (source: [Airflow documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/xcoms.html))

Answer (score 1):

The return value is saved in an [Xcom](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#xcoms). You can access it from another operator as it is shown in [this](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/example_xcom.py) example.

```
data = ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='get_data_from_bq')
```